# How to save API keys to .env using application's GUI the safe way?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on application that will be storing data from many sources. The thing is that there will be 2-3 new sources each month, so I look for a way to allow users to add new keys within my application. The data will be highly sensitive, so I want to do it securely.

---

I don't want to **enable `putenv()` function** or **read the .env file as a text**.
Right now my `@store` action in the controller looks like that:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'customer_api' => 'required',
        'secret_api' => 'required',
        'edition_id' => 'required'
      ]);

      $edition = $request->input('edition_id');
      $secret = $request->input('secret_api');
      $customer = $request->input('customer_api');

      putenv("GF_SECRET_ED$edition=$secret");
      putenv("GF_CUSTOMER_ED$edition=$customer");

      return redirect('/editions/' . $edition . "#dev")->with('success', 'API keys added');
    }
```

And I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to add those keys to `.env`, then to define those 3rd party keys in `config/services.php` 
Couldn't find anything in docs. Working on Laravel 6.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what about using a database, maybe you should consider it in one of your options

Comment: Modifying the .env from the app itself is unsafe by default.

Comment: Usually you let your controller grab values from your config, and your config can be delegated to .env. You could add it to the config by middleware or even a serviceprovider(by default AppServiceProvider) If you want some examples, I can share :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify env in your app dosen't right

you have two choices :

1- use database

2- using file and maybe with json format to easily retrieve data